# What is the proper way of continuing with an async pattern call in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, observable

I have a method what must call an async method that uses an Observable and must return a value. This value is getted calling the async method.

I have two ways to solve this problem:

**Way 1: Using a Promise**

```
methodThatUseAPromise(){

      const promise:Promise<...>= new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                     {
                          service.someObservableMethod(...).subscribe(
                                    data => resolve(data),
                                    error => reject(error))
                     });

      return promise;
```

}

Then this method is called:

```
methodThatuseAPromise().then(....)
```

**Way 2: Using a Subject**

```
methodThatUseASubject() {

   subject:Subject<...>= new Subject();

   service.someObservableMethod(...).subscribe(
                                        data => subject.next(data),
                                        error => subject.error(error))


   return subject;

}
```

Then this method is called:

```
methodThatUseASubject().subscribe(....)
```

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use your `Observable` without puttiing it into `Promise`

Comment: This is surely just asking what people prefer between promises and observables? It is completely opinion-based. I prefer pure observables and only resorting to promises where absolutely necessary. But I do see people mixing observables and promises on StackOverflow (generally because they don't understand observables).

Comment: @KurtHamilton good point! But I believe that we can use Observables and Promises in one code when necessary. I can imagine the good rule when we use Observables when we expect stream (many elements) and Promise when there is only one request.

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga Yes - that sounds like a perfectly reasonable convention. But it is still an opinion :)

Comment: @KurtHamilton agree on that! But good practices are based on opinions, aren't they? :)

Comment: In general I don't prefer mixing observables and promises. But in your case, if you expect to use only the first value from the observable `someObservableMethod()`, both solutions work. But if you need the stream to persist beyond the first value, only solution 2 works. Remember that observables were introduced to overcome some of the limitations of promises.

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga I think this is why StackOverflow doesn't like opinion-based questions - there's no right or wrong, especially if everyone has a valid point of view. That's why I have voted to close.

Comment: As someone else said is kinda an opinion based answer. I personally use both Observable and promise pattern. Since it's situational when I personally use a promise instead of an Observable there's not much else to say. This question should be closed as Kurt said, SO is not made for this.